# sql query to group file sizes by range with the sums

Tags: sql, sql-server

sql (sql server) query to group file sizes by range and output the sums
output should have 
file sizes in Megs
 < 20, 20-50, 50-100, 100+
I will need the count and sum of each bracket

table MyFiles (ID, filesize)
output 
< 20, < 20 count, 20-50, 20-50 count, 50-100, 50-100 count, 100+, 100+ count

I am not sure how to group them into ranges and get a sum AND a count

Comment: Use a CASE expression(s).

Answer (score 3):

You could use a case statement but it would get complex if your criteria (banding) were to change.

I would use an in-memory table to hold the ranges and do a simple join onto your data table as this keeps the end query real simple and makes for changes to the banding down the line much easier to cater for:

```
 -- In memory table to hold ranges
 DECLARE @Range TABLE(
    Id INT
    ,MinRange INT
    ,MaxRange INT 
    ,Dsc VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO @Range VALUES(1, 0, 20, '< 20')
INSERT INTO @Range VALUES(2, 20, 50, '20 - 50')
INSERT INTO @Range VALUES(3, 50, 100, '50 - 100')
INSERT INTO @Range VALUES(4, 100, NULL, '100 +')

-- Mock of your Data Table
DECLARE @Data TABLE(
    Id INT,
    FileSize INT)

INSERT INTO @Data VALUES(1, 100)
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES(2, 101)
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES(3, 19)
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES(4, 50)
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES(5, 99)

-- Group By Query to determine count and size of files by range
SELECT R.Dsc
     , SUM(D.FileSize) as TotalFileSize
     , COUNT(*) as NumberOfFiles FROM @Data D
    INNER JOIN @Range R ON (D.FileSize >= R.MinRange AND D.FileSize < R.MaxRange)
                        OR (D.FileSize >= R.MinRange AND R.MaxRange IS NULL)
        GROUP BY R.Dsc
```

Results of the above:

```
 +----------+---------------+---------------+
 |   Dsc    | TotalFileSize | NumberOfFiles |
 +----------+---------------+---------------+
 | < 20     |            19 |             1 |
 | 100 +    |           201 |             2 |
 | 50 - 100 |           149 |             2 |
 +----------+---------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a case statement and once I saw it - it was pretty easy to do.
I simplified what I was using but to show the sql

```
select  GroupName,
sum(
case when FileSize between 1 and (1024 * 1024 * 20) then FileSize else 0 end
) as '< 20', 
SUM(
case when FileSize between 1 and (1024 * 1024 * 20) then 1 else 0 end
) as '< 20 count',
sum(
case when FileSize between (1024 * 1024 * 20 -1) and (1024 * 1024 * 50) then FileSize else 0 end
) as '20 - 50', 
SUM(
case when FileSize between (1024 * 1024 * 20 -1) and (1024 * 1024 * 50) then 1 else 0 end
) as '20 - 50 count',
sum(
case when FileSize between (1024 * 1024 * 50 -1) and (1024 * 1024 * 100) then FileSize else 0 end
) as '50 - 100', 
SUM(
case when FileSize between (1024 * 1024 * 50 -1) and (1024 * 1024 * 100) then 1 else 0 end
) as '50 - 100 count',
sum(
case when FileSize > (1024 * 1024 * 100 -1)  then FileSize else 0 end
) as '100+', 
SUM(
case when FileSize > (1024 * 1024 * 100 -1) then 1 else 0 end
) as '100+ count',
sum(
FileSize 
) as 'Total Size', 
SUM(
case when FileSize > 0 then 1 else 0 end
) as 'Total Count'
 FROM FileEntries
Group By GroupName
```